# What are the requirements for building a Web Mapping and analysis Site?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, web-mapping, openlayers-2, web-service

I want to make a site like [bhuvan](http://bhuvan-noeda.nrsc.gov.in/theme/thematic/theme.php) in which it can provide different layers of information and also tools for performing GIS analysis

I know three main requirements :

- client side scripting (openLayers)
- Web services (a Map server) + Tiling/Caching Services
- Database (PostGIS)

I have ArcGIS desktop installed on my computer...and we can digitise many of the layers.

My questions are :

1. How can I put these layers I created in ArcGIS in my website i.e., how to publish these maps to any open web services.
2. For what purpose we need Database like postGIS. How are web services differ from databases. With out database, can we build a
   webGIS?

Comment: According to question 1.. you need to put the data in geoserver and publish as wms service..question 2 yes we need data base to store and link large data with the map (some times its not possible to attach large data directly to the map)...question 3. not sure ..try Dijkstra's algorithm (not sure) OR use postgis functions..but its not easy to find this stuff in open source...question 4.. Java and the java script..question 5 I think the open layer

Comment: As we are getting each and every data from webservices itself, why should we need database then. I mean if I publish everything to webserver and then use them again by sending a request through the webbrowser..what is the database actually do..can you please explain it clearly? I really dont get it.

Comment: and also if we need database, where should I go and learn for creating or managing my database? i am totally confused here. please help me!!! Thank you!! :)

Comment: Your question is huge & I am actively researching your question..

Comment: You may want to split your Question into 5 Questions to better fit the Stack Exchange Q & A format.

Comment: @PolyGeo that's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you go through the OpenGeo workshop: [Introduction to the OpenGeo Suite](http://workshops.opengeo.org/suiteintro/)

Though this workshop deals with the Opengeo suite in particular, it has enough general advice and knowledge, to serve as a good starting point.

Now let me try to answer your questions:

> How to publish these maps to any open webservices?

The easiest way is to take your shapefiles that you created in ArcMap, and upload those into PostGIS. Using a GIS server(either geoserver or MapServer), you can create web service. The WMS and WFS are the standard GIS enable services which give out the data in a open GIS format.

You will then require a client that can use those services. If you want to show the services/Map in the web browser, then you would have to create a Openlayers based webpage.

If you want to see the services/Map in your desktop based GIS software like ArcGIS, or any of the FOSS like Qgis, or udigg, you can consume the service directly in those.

> For what purpose we need Database like postGIS. How are webservices
> differ from databases. With out database, can we build a webGIS?

A database just contains the data. A webservice is required to query the database, and provide information in a standard complaint format. The webservice and database are complimentary to each other.

(As as aside, it is possible to make a webservice use your shapefiles directly. It is not recommended because the performance is better with a database.)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're quite new to web mapping, learning all of these technologies will take time (albeit a worthwhile investment).

In the meantime, you could probably achieve your objectives in an afternoon using a hosted map publication platform like [MangoMap](http://www.mangomap.com).

**Disclaimer**: I am the Founder of MangoMap.